# PostgreSql 12 - Can't see table details \dt (table) but can see all tables \dt

Tags: postgresql

I have a custom schema and one table in it. Following answers about searching through custom schemas I have modified by *search_path* to include new schema.

I can see now all objects in the new schema, so this one works:

```
xekata_dev=> \dt
                List of relations
 Schema |     Name     | Type  |      Owner
--------+--------------+-------+-----------------
 xekata | TestNodeBase | table | xekata_user_web
(1 row)
```

Now when I want to see table details I do:

```
xekata_dev=> \d TestNodeBase
Did not find any relation named "TestNodeBase".
```

which shows nothing... :(

I tried different ways to but nothing works:

```
xekata_dev-> \d xekata.TestNodeBase
Did not find any relation named "xekata.TestNodeBase".
```

I am logged as *xekata_user_web* and my *search_path* is:

```
xekata_dev=> show search_path;
  search_path
----------------
 xekata, public
```

What's going on? Why I can't see table details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a case sensitive table name (which is [strongly discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)) so now you need to use double quotes every time you access it:

```
\d xekata."TestNodeBase"
```

I highly recommend to stop using those dreaded quoted identifies. Forget that double quotes exists when dealing with SQL.

Comment: such a facepalm! Thanks for explanining this. Snake case for the win!